# What's the word for the condition where you need to defecate?

Tags: single-word-requests

"hungry" describes the condition where one craves intake of more food. what is the English name for the condition where one needs to expel the end result?

Comment: I doubt it's `shitty`

Comment: @rubenvb: well, "hungry" does't mean that desires to "hang"

Comment: Dunno about America, but in Britain you're [taken short](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_taken_short_mean). Sometimes it can also mean you're desperate to urinate, but normally that's *bursting* or *busting [for a pee]*.

Comment: Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56938/is-there-a-word-akin-to-hungry-or-thirsty-that-implies-a-need-to-urinate

Comment: Do other languages have words that have this precise meaning?

Comment: If it's pathologically frequent, the condition is termed [rectal tenesmus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenesmus).

Comment: "I need to go see a man about a horse." - I know about this expression, but I can't recall ever hearing anyone actually use it (in real life).

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: In Esperanto, the word "fekavida" is easily and naturally formed, meaning, literally, "defecate-urgently-wanting"...:)

Answer (score 6):

There is no common word that describes this condition. American English speakers will politely say:

> I need to go to the bathroom.

British English speakers may say something like:

> I need to go to the loo.
>
> I need to visit the WC.

None of these are explicit about what kind of waste is being eliminated, but in polite company you don't usually need to be exact about your toilet activities.

There are a wide variety of less polite alternatives, which I started to try to list, but gave up.

Comment: "Touching cloth" is a personal fave :)

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard anyone say "I need to visit the WC".

Comment: I'm not a brit: what *do* you/they say? Or maybe they just don't poop at all.

Comment: _loo_ is idiomatic, _WC_ isn't.

Comment: "I'm crowning!"

Comment: Yes, I need to go to the _loo_ or _toilet_ would be the modern British parlance

Comment: turtle-heading? :)

Answer (score 2):

My grandmother would never be more explicit than to say she "needed to powder her nose".  The fact that she didn't wear makeup was quite beside the fact.
On the other end of the spectrum, others might have a "need to take a dump".

Answer (score 1):

*[Fecal urgency](http://www.healthhype.com/urgency-to-have-a-bowel-movement-and-urge-fecal-incontinence.html)* is the term for *really* needing to go.

Answer (score 0):

Prairie dogging, as depicted in the movie *Rat Race* (2001):

> Kimberly Pear: [Kimberly needs to go to the bathroom] Dad, I'm
>   *prairie dogging* it!  Randy Pear: What the hell does that mean?  Jason Pear: You know, like when a prairie dog sticks his head in and
>   out of the ground.  Randy Pear: Oh.  [Five seconds later]  Bev Pear:
>   Ugh!  Randy Pear: Ohh, god, I do not wanna picture that!

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0250687/quotes